# Why is .ajaxForm() not working when the site is loaded over https?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I've reduced the page down to the bare minimum to recreate this problem. It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="//malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $('#signupform').ajaxForm(
                            function(new_html) {
                                alert("testing!");
                            });
                });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="signupform" action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.email }}
            {{ form.university }}
            <button type="submit">
                GET EARLY ACCESS
            </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically just a from and some jquery which uses .ajaxForm() to modify the form.

When I load the site over HTTP it works as expected: when the button is pressed an alert with "testing!" shows, the POST is sent out in the background, and there is no redirection. When I run it over HTTPS there's a problem though, it's like the javascript isn't even there. When I click the submit button there is no alert and the site redirects normally.

I've tested this locally with HTTP with the standard `$ python manage.py runserver`, and with HTTPS using [django-sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver) with `$ python manage.py runsslserver`. I've also run the app on our Heroku staging server and got the exact same http/https difference.

What could be causing this javascript to behave differently when the site is loaded over https as opposed to http?

Update: per comment, here is the javascript console output:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:8000/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js'. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Which changes the nature of the question. The question is now: why is

> //malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

not being loaded over https? (not sure if I should delete and repost with this new question)

Comment: Is there any output in your browser's Javascript console?

Comment: github is not a cdn, you are better off using service like cdnjs 
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js does a 301 redirect to http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js which ends up being a unsecured resource. Hence the error. I frankly don't know why they would do that. That's the issue stopping you then.

Comment: Interesting. I may try downloading jquery.form.js and storing it as a static file. Would that be a viable solution?

Comment: yes you can do that or check other CDN that gives you jquery.form.js

Comment: If it works, you can either upvote it or accept it, though it is slightly different from the original problem.

Comment: this cdn working for me   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.3.0/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha512-YUkaLm+KJ5lQXDBdqBqk7EVhJAdxRnVdT2vtCzwPHSweCzyMgYV/tgGF4/dCyqtCC2eCphz0lRQgatGVdfR0ww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>